# CSS: margin-bottom not working and contents of div tag are showing out of border box

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to lift the  navigation links in my header section. They all are in a div class "links" which is under div class "headers".

But the `margin-bottom` property doesn't have any impact.

So to check whether there is any change in position I made the border around the div class "links".

But when border appeared all the navigation links are shown out of the box.

Also there is no impact of `margin-bottom` on the border box.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L2k67eyx/

PLEASE let me know whats wrong with my code? Also is there any rules I must know when does `margin` properties work?

CODE Snippet:

```css
body{
 height: 100vh;
 margin: 0px;
}
.header{

 background-color: white;
 height:50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-style: "Roboto";
 font-size: 25px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid;
 border-bottom-color: #cccccc;
}
.content{
 position: relative;
 background-color: white;
 height: 90%;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

.logo{
 float: left;
 left: 0px;
 padding-right: 50px;
}
#logo:hover{
 background: transparent;
}
.links{
 display: block;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;/*NOT WORKING*/
 /*right: 100px;*/
 border-style:solid;
 border-color: black;

 outline-style: solid;
 outline-color: green;
}
a{
 position: relative;
 right: 0px;
 top: 25px;

 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;

 color:black;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-weight: 200;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
 background-color:#cccccc; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
 
 <title>Home Page</title>
 <style type="text/css">

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
   <a href="home.html"><img id="logo"src="logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="links">   
   <a href="home.html">Home</a>
   <a href="home.html">Offers</a>
   <a href="home.html">Login</a>
   <a href="register.html">Register</a>
   <a href="home.html">Contact</a>
   <a href="home.html">About</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div clear="both"></div>
 <div class="content">
 
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“But when border appeared all the navigation links are shown out of the box.”_ - well you moved them all down by relative positioning with `top: 25px`, so not sure what else you expected to happen.

Comment: what you need .please explain .

Comment: Your `.links` div does have it's `margin-bottom` working. What are you trying to do ?
Your `a` links are out of the box because you are using `float: right` on `.links` and  as said @CBroe `top: 25px` on your `a`

Comment: @Arkellys I want to lift my navigation links above the bottom line of header section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should to remove margin top:0px in tag a style to be

```
a{
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            top: 0px;

            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;

            color:black;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            font-weight: 200;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```